# Unable to set password error while Mysql Data Migration

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-14.04

I am trying to migrate mysql databases from one server to another. I am following these steps for the migration (270GB of data including databases and users in datadir):

```
sudo service mysql stop 
sudo apt-get purge mysql-server-5.5 mysql-common
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/mysql
sudo rm -rf /etc/mysql
sudo ln -s <path to datadir>/mysql /var/lib/mysql
sudo apt-get clean 
sudo apt-get purge mysql* 
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install -f 
sudo apt-get install mysql-server-5.5
```

This asks for root password, which I try to set accordingly. However, I am getting the following response:

```
Configuring mysql-server-5.5 

Unable to set password for the MySQL "root" user                             
                                                                               
  An error occurred while setting the password for the MySQL administrative    
  user. This may have happened because the account already has a password, or  
  because of a communication problem with the MySQL server.                    
                                                                               
  You should check the account's password after the package installation.      
                                                                               
  Please read the /usr/share/doc/mysql-server-5.5/README.Debian file for more  
  information.
```

Note that I followed the same steps on another ubuntu server (dev) based on the same AMI and was successful in doing the setup. The only variable between the two is data.
I cannot afford much downtime, and therefore using rsync for data replication.

I know that both the ubuntu and mysql versions are old, but this migration is necessary and has strict deadlines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution here was pretty simple.

Rebooting the ubuntu server after following the steps to purge mysql* worked for me. Steps:

```
sudo service mysql stop 
sudo apt-get purge mysql-server-5.5 mysql-common
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/mysql
sudo rm -rf /etc/mysql
sudo ln -s <path to datadir>/mysql /var/lib/mysql
sudo apt-get clean 
sudo apt-get purge mysql*
```

**Reboot the ubuntu machine.**
Then:

```
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install -f 
sudo apt-get install mysql-server-5.5
```